# Using arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, select-by-attribute

I have difficulty to understand how to use "arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management".

I not understand how to write a query.
I want to select the records > 0.

I am attaching my code:

```
import os,arcpy
shp=(r"C:\Lavoro\\A3.shp")
fil=[f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(shp)]
print fil
qq=fil[7]
print qq
qq2=fil[8]
print qq2
##exp= '!fil[7]!'>0   #fot test1

##arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("shp","NEW_SELECTION",fil[7]>0)#test0
##arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(shp,"NEW_SELECTION",exp)   #test1
##arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("shp","NEW_SELECTION",'!' + fil[7] + '!'>0)#test2
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("shp","NEW_SELECTION",'! + fil[7] + !'>0)#test3

print "End"
```

I also ask you to explain to me how use   !    "    '  . I don't understand the criteria.

Comment: The sql statement can vary depending on what type of database you are using,  a little trick is to start a model using the selectbyattribute tool, then put in your sql statement into the tool parameters and export to a python script.  the sql formatting will then be correct.

Comment: Or just use the AddFieldDelimiters tool.  This tool is designed for the purpose of not having to know the correct syntax for the the specific database.  It will add the correct delimiters for any source.

Answer (score 5):

The third argument to the [SelectLayerByAttributes](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/select-layer-by-attribute.htm) function is an SQL expression in string format. If you are familiar with the Select By Attributes dialog window it is essentially what you would type there.

The [ArcMap SQL Reference](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/sql-reference-for-query-expressions-used-in-arcgis.htm) should help you in constructing valid queries. Important points to remember are that the field names must be enclosed in double quotes and string values in single quotes, while numeric values require no quotation e.g.

```
'"my_field" = \'my_str_val\'' # Note the escaped quotations within the string
```

In your specific case, I would do the following:

```
# Using string formatting to insert your field name into the expression.
exp = '"{}" > 0'.format(fil[7]) 
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(shp,"NEW_SELECTION",exp)
```

The '!' character is used to specify fields in the [field calculator](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/calculate-field-examples.htm) using Python and should not be confused with SQL syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to use the exclamation marks around the field name, this is only used within field calculator.  The select layer by attribute page has a code sample for selecting numeric field values.

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/select-layer-by-attribute.htm

' "{}" > 0 '.format(qq)

Double quotes around field name and since field value is numeric you do not need quotes around the zero value.  Finally, surround entire expression with single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

To take away some guess work with the field names and " and/or ' signs in SQL expressions you can use [AddFieldDelimiters](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/addfielddelimiters.htm):

> Adds field delimiters to a field name to allow for use in SQL
>   expressions.
>
> The field delimiters used in an SQL expression differ depending on the
>   format of the queried data. For instance, file geodatabases and
>   shapefiles use double quotation marks (" "), personal geodatabases use
>   square brackets ([ ]), and enterprise geodatabases don't use field
>   delimiters. The function can take away the guess work in ensuring that
>   the field delimiters used with your SQL expression are the correct
>   ones.